# Sametime install on ubuntu giving error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sametime

I am using

```
sudo apt-get install sametime-connect
```

and getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sametime-connect:i386 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up jenkins (2.71) ...
Found an incorrect Java version
Java version found:
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)

Aborting
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have .deb file locally , i am using ubuntu14.04 64 bit.
can anyone provide help in this area,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Jenkins: the version you installed is incompatible with java 1.7.0_131. Every time you use apt-get to install another package, it complains that jenkins installation is broken.

I am going to assume you are running a linux distribution like Ubuntu 14.04. If this is the case, you should be able to fix the issue by doing the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Then you need to change the default version of java with:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /path/to/java-8
```

For example:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Now you can run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now jenkins should upgrade/install correctly. After this, apt should work again without errors/complaints.